# Trouble generating wifi hotspot in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hot-spot

What happened was I wanted to change my WiFi hotspot default name, so I followed instructions as mentioned [here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/09/how-to-create-wi-fi-hotspot-in-ubuntu.html). The following commands were written by me on the terminal:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

I changed the default name and password but now I am not able to generate my WiFi hotspot. Anyone help me out, please. My Ubuntu version is 18.04 and I have a wired network connection. It is perfectly fine even if I get the default hotspot name but I just need my hotspot running. I also restarted my laptop.
Here is a screenshot of /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot file

[image: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot]

Comment: please provied more description about what's on the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the Hotspot with the Network-Manager GUI, it creates the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`. In that file it is possible to edit the SSID and the password.

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

The content of the file is:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=0bf627gd-8e34-48c6-865a-06f898b4y1hb
type=wifi
autoconnect=true
permissions=
secondaries=

[wifi]
hidden=false
mac-address=YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE_MAC_ADDRESS
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=
ssid=SSID_NAME

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=YOUR_WIFI_AP_PASSWORD

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

To enable autostart you have to set the parameter autoconnect to true. Then restart your computer because the command: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` for network restart seems not to work correctly.

After restart you can use the nmcli command to start the access point.

```
nmcli con up Hotspot ifname YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE
```

`YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE` you can find out with the command `iwconfig`.

Make sure you install `network-manager` and its dependencies to use `nmcli`.

Comment: How to start the access point automatically after each system restart?